# using express route handlers and promises -what are the best practices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I'm currently working on a web project and I'm trying to understand Node.js and express. I know about that for achiving asynchronous easy to maintain code we should use promises , but I'm confused about the following scenario:
I have a route handler for REST API , should I return a promise ? even if there is no Async work done there ? 
i.e :

```
dummy_router.post("/", passport.authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
      var result = some_simple_functionality();
      if (result) {
          fulfill(result)
      } else {
          reject(err)
      }

  }).catch(function (error) {
      res.status(400).send('400: failed t :: ' + error + '\n');
  });
});
```

also second question on same issue . if I am performing some async tasks and have promises containing them then is this a good practice ?

```
dummy_router.post("/", passport.authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
  some_promise().then((result) => {

  }, (err) => {

  }).catch(function (error) {
    res.status(400).send('400: failed t :: ' + error + '\n');
  });
});
```

Comment: Your first example is manufacturing a promise when none is needed.  There is no reason to wrap synchronous code in a promise.  That just adds complexity that is not needed and adds no benefit.  Your second example appears to be using an actual asynchronous operation that returns a promise.  That looks generally correct, but it is unclear why you have both an error handler on your `.then()` and a `.catch()`.  Pick one or the other and be aware that a reject handler that does not rethrow or return a rejected promise will change the promise into a fulfilled promise (overriding the rejection).

Comment: So, your empty reject handler is "eating" all rejections.  That's bad.  You can just remove it and let the `.catch()` do its job.

Comment: thanks , this make sense . I knew the first example adds unnecessary complication , just wanted to know if I understood it correctly. about the catch() and reject handler ,  if I am doing some work in case of the some_promise() failure and then chain it to  another promise is there justification to use both the rejection handler and the catch() then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer:

Your first example is manufacturing a promise when none is needed. There is no reason to wrap synchronous code in a promise. That just adds complexity that is not needed and adds no benefit. Express does not do anything with the return value from a request handler so there is no use in returning a promise from that at all.

Your second example appears to be using an actual asynchronous operation that returns a promise. That looks generally correct, but it is unclear why you have both an error handler on your .then() and a .catch(). Pick one or the other and be aware that a reject handler that does not rethrow or return a rejected promise will change the promise into a fulfilled promise (overriding the rejection).

So, when you do this:

```
  some_promise().then((result) => {

  }, (err) => {
      // unless you rethrow here, this will "handle" the error
      // and the promise will become fulfilled, not rejected
  }).catch(function (error) {
      res.status(400).send('400: failed t :: ' + error + '\n');
  });
```

The `(err) => {}` handler is causing your promise rejection to get eaten unless you rethrow or return a rejected promise from that.

So, probably all you want is this:

```
  some_promise().then((result) => {
      // code to process result here
      res.send(...);
  }).catch(function (error) {
      res.status(400).send('400: failed t :: ' + error + '\n');
  });
```

There is rarely ever a reason to use both a `.then()` reject handler (the 2nd argument to `.then()` and a subsequent `.catch()` handler.

> Is there justification to use both the rejection handler and the catch() then?

No.  There are a few uncommon situations why you might want both, but in this case (and in most cases), just having the `.catch()` handler is all you need.